# The method getResources() and context is undefined for the type

Tags: android, android-context, getstring

I use the `getString()` to become String from string.xml.
In my class (non-activity) does not work:

- context.getResources().getString()
- getResources().getString()
- context.getResources().getString()

How do I get the String to this class?

```
public class myClass{
     public String[] myInfo(String ID) {
        String myString = getRessources().getString(R.string.myString);
     };
}
```

Comment: your class does not extend activity. you need to pass the context to get resources

Comment: Follow the answer below. As mentioned in the answer you need the activity context to get resources. pass it to the constructor of the non-activity class and use the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to call `context.getResources().getString()`, but you have to pass in a context in order to do that.

You can create a constructor, that takes that parameter for example:

```
Context context;

public myClass(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```